# mysql_select_db() causes my $_POST variables to come up empty

Tags: php, database, database-connection

When I use mysql_select_db() my $_POST variables come up empty, if I comment it out then my $_POST variables are fine but my queries can execute. (no database selected).  I do have my connection file included.

Here is the breakdown of my code:

```
<?php 
require_once('connections/conn1.php');
include('functions.php');

print_r ($_POST);//Outputs "Array()" to the screen
if(isset($_POST['Login']))
{

    mysql_select_db($database_conn1, $conn1);
    // if this line is commented out then the print_r($_POST) 
    //above outputs all the correct information.

    $select = 'SELECT record_id, username, active FROM table1 WHERE username = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']).'" AND password = "'.mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password'])).'"';

    $query = mysql_query($select, $conn1) or die(mysql_error());

}
    ?>  

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Username</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="username" name="username" size="32" value="" />
      </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" id="password" name="password" size="32" value="" />
      </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you have a `mysql_connect()` set? Have you tried adding `die(mysql_error())` to the end of your `mysql_select_db()` to make sure it's not dying?

Comment: I added `or die(mysql_error());` to the end of mysql_select_db() and nothing changed.  My `require_once('connections/conn1.php');` includes the code my `mysql_connect()` along with the hostname, database, username, and password, I also have an `or die(mysql_error());` at the end of the `mysql_connect`.  What I mean by my $_POST variable is empty is that when I hit the line `print_r ($_POST);//Outputs "Array()" to the screen
` all I see as output to the screen is `Array()` when It should output an array of all of my post variables.

Comment: That would be the case when the form is submitted, not before, and in this case the mysql_select_db() wouldn't be called, as it depends on the $_POST['login'] index being set, i.e. when the form is submitted, hence when the $_POST array is not empty

Comment: After I submit the form, this line `if(isset($_POST['Login']))` comes up false, so to check what value is getting passed in from my form I put the line `print_r ($_POST);//Outputs "Array()" to the screen` and it still comes up as an empty array after I submit the form.

Comment: Err, you're not posting any value labeled 'login'. It's a button but i'ts not really a form field - I might be wrong but I've never come across an instal

Move the print_r($_POST); statement to the very top of the file and check the results; that way there's no possible way for any erroneous code to empty your $_POST variable.

Comment: I tried moving the `print_r($_POST);` to the very first line, It still comes up empty after I submit the form.  Keep in mind if I comment out the line `mysql_select_db($database_conn1, $conn1);
` My `print_r($_POST);` outputs all the correct values and keys including the `$_POST['Login']` value and key. here is an example of what the output from the line `print_r($_POST);` should be <br />

Comment: here is the output `Array ( [username] => admin [password] => password123 [Login] => Login ) `

Answer (score 0):

Put mysql_select_db($database_conn1, $conn1) inside your conn1.php file.

Comment: After I submit the form, this line `if(isset($_POST['Login']))
` comes up false, so to check what value is getting passed in from my form I put the line `print_r ($_POST);//Outputs "Array()" to the screen` and it still comes up as an empty array.  I will try to put the `mysql_select_db()` in my conn1.php file now.

Comment: Adding mysql_select_db() to my conn1.php file did not change anything.  The $_POST variable still comes up as an empty array after form submission.

Answer (score 0):

I had nearly the same problem... Look up "Send database-name by $_POST-value not work" here.
I surround my hole php-code with if (isset($_POST['dbName'])) {php-code} and it works :) It takes me about 8 hours! I hope this will hely someone!